# Is anybody able to show the clock in beamer?

Tags: beamer, tdclock

I wonder whether there is anyone who is able to show the clock in a beamer presentation. I have not come across any working example. Following the tdclock documentation, I compiled the MWE below. It shows only blank boxes where the date and time are supposed to appear, see pdf attached.
I would appreciate any advice.[image: pdf output]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\usepackage[font=Helv,timeinterval=60]{tdclock}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\initclock\large{\tdyear-\tdmonth-\tdday
\quad\tdhours:\tdminutes}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\title[]{Main Title}
\author[]{Zilore Mumba}
\institute[]{Unza}

\usepackage[font=Helv,timeinterval=60]{tdclock}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\initclock\large{\tdyear-\tdmonth-\tdday\quad\tdhours:\tdminutes}}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 \initclock

\title{Beamer Presentation}
\author{Zilore Mumba}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{first slide}
content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works fine for me. But you need the adobe reader as pdf viewer.

Comment: The operating system is also relevant:  it works with Adobe Reader on Microsoft, but not on GNU/Linux.

Comment: It definitely works fine under Linux with Adobe Reader 9.5 as long as javascript is enabled

Comment: @ArTourter How does one do that? I don’t see any likely options under Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, am on ubuntu. I will check adobe reader and javascript.

Comment: Hello, I can see it works on Windows, but I still cannot get it to work on Linux. Thanks all.

Comment: @Thérèse `Edit>Preferences>JavaScript`  and select "Enable Acrobat JavaScript". This is with the binary straight from Adobe.

Comment: Make sure the package you got from your repository includes the javascript part. On the package from adobe it is in `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/JavaScripts/JSByteCodeLin.bin`. If this is not there is means your distribution removed it. I just moved it away and I get the same as the screenshots from the OP.